# Cannot access webpage (in a docker) with nginx instance on a virtual machine (504 Gateway Time-out)

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, home-assistant

i’m pretty clueless right now. I cannot reach the webpage of a plugin called "File Editor" in Home Assistant VM If I go through Nginx. I’ve got 504 Gateway Time-out in the Iframe. I can access to it from local IP. I disabled firefox browser protection.

[What the webpage should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/64ejP.png)
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jf9fA.png)

I tried with a fresh browser, different Nginx config etc. Any clue would be appreciated!

In File Editor logs :

`INFO:2023-10-05 15:33:33,214:hass_configurator.configurator:127.0.0.1 - "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 - INFO:2023-10-05 15:34:03,282:hass_configurator.configurator:127.0.0.1 - "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -`

But first, this is my actual configuration

```
Home Assistant 2023.9.3 (supervised on debian 12)
Supervisor 2023.10.0
** Interface : 20230911.0 - latest**
```

Network :
3 virtual network card with different VLAN (VLAN 1, Wifi and IOT). The VLAN1 network card, is the default one.

in configuration.yaml

```
http:
  use_x_forwarded_for: true
  trusted_proxies:
    - 192.168.xxx.3      # IP of my Nginx server
    - 172.30.32.0/23  # IP subnet from internal HAS Docker
    - 127.0.0.1 (not sure if needed)
```

Docker containers

[Docker container](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xvOWw.png)

For my nginx :

```
Nginx Proxy Manager in a Docker in a DMZ VLAN
```

HAS nginx conf. (I tried a lot of stuff). Websocket activated

```
proxy_buffering off;   
 location / {
        add_header  X-Robots-Tag "noindex, nofollow, nosnippet, noarchive";
        proxy_pass http://192.168.xxx.52:8123;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
       proxy_set_header        Host $host;
       proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
       proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
       proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
    location /api { # Home Assistant API SSL reverse proxy
        proxy_pass http://192.168.xxx.52:8123/api;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }
    location /auth { # Home Assistant API SSL reverse proxy
        proxy_pass http://192.168.xxx.52:8123/auth;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }
```

My Nginx log

```
[05/Oct/2023:12:50:59 -0700] - 200 200 - GET https home.exemple.com "/core_configurator/ingress?auth_callback=1&code=2fb00fa68ca043iophjswfoiahs96939141f&state=eyJoYXNzVXJsIjoiaHR0cHM6posjdfgposjdfpoddsjfpozovL2hvbWUuamVkZHVmZi5jb20vIn0%3D&storeToken=true" [Client 192.168.xxx.250] [Length 3126] [Gzip 2.91] [Sent-to 192.168.xxx.52] "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/117.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/117.0.2045.55" "-"
[05/Oct/2023:12:50:59 -0700] - 200 200 - POST https home.exemple.com "/auth/token" [Client 192.168.xxx.250] [Length 344] [Gzip -] [Sent-to 192.168.xxx.52] "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/117.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/117.0.2045.55" "https://home.exemple.com/core_configurator/ingress?auth_callback=1&code=2fb00fa68ca043iophjswfoiahs96939141f&state=eyJoYXNzVXJsIjoiaHR0cHM6posjdfgposjdfpoddsjfpozovL2hvbWUuamVkZHVmZi5jb20vIn0%3D&storeToken=true"
[05/Oct/2023:12:50:59 -0700] - 200 200 - GET https home.exemple.com "/manifest.json" [Client 192.168.xxx.250] [Length 933] [Gzip -] [Sent-to 192.168.xxx.52] "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/117.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/117.0.2045.55" "https://home.exemple.com/core_configurator/ingress?auth_callback=1&code=2fb00fa68ca043iophjswfoiahs96939141f&state=eyJoYXNzVXJsIjoiaHR0cHM6posjdfgposjdfpoddsjfpozovL2hvbWUuamVkZHVmZi5jb20vIn0%3D&storeToken=true"
[05/Oct/2023:12:51:00 -0700] - 200 200 - GET https home.exemple.com "/api/hassio/app/entrypoint.js" [Client 192.168.xxx.250] [Length 258] [Gzip -] [Sent-to 192.168.xxx.52] "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/117.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/117.0.2045.55" "https://home.exemple.com/core_configurator/ingress"
[05/Oct/2023:12:51:09 -0700] - 101 101 - GET https home.exemple.com "/api/websocket" [Client 192.168.xxx.250] [Length 71956] [Gzip -] [Sent-to 192.168.xxx.52] "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/118.0" "-"
[05/Oct/2023:12:51:09 -0700] - 101 101 - GET https home.exemple.com "/api/websocket" [Client 192.168.xxx.250] [Length 51] [Gzip -] [Sent-to 192.168.xxx.52] "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/118.0" "-"
[05/Oct/2023:12:51:09 -0700] - 200 200 - GET https home.exemple.com "/core_configurator/ingress" [Client 192.168.xxx.250] [Length 3126] [Gzip 2.91] [Sent-to 192.168.xxx.52] "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/118.0" "-"
[05/Oct/2023:12:51:10 -0700] - 200 200 - GET https home.exemple.com "/api/hassio/app/entrypoint.js" [Client 192.168.xxx.250] [Length 258] [Gzip -] [Sent-to 192.168.xxx.52] "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/118.0" "https://home.exemple.com/core_configurator/ingress"
[05/Oct/2023:12:51:10 -0700] - 200 200 - GET https home.exemple.com "/service_worker.js" [Client 192.168.xxx.250] [Length 69429] [Gzip -] [Sent-to 192.168.xxx.52] "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/118.0" "-"
```

I tried with few configuration in nginx, but cannot get it connected